# Can we use generic to allow only specific types instead of any type <T>?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have three isolated public classes (no IS-A relationship) A, B and C. I want to define a field in C such that it's type can either be A or B.

Currently I'm achieving this by defining C as below:

```
class A{} class B{}

public class C<T> {

    private T obj;

    public C(T param){
        if ( !(param instanceof A)
                || !(param instanceof B) ) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Only types A and B are allowed!");
        }
        this.obj = param;
    }

}
```

Above code will throw exception only at runtime. But what I would rather prefer is to throw error at compile time itself to generate a compiler error in case any type other than A or B is used to construct C.

Comment: Nope. You can't do that.

Comment: T extends A is what you look?

Comment: Do you process objects of type `A` and `B` differently or do they have something like a common "interface" (strictly conceptual, not compile-time dependent speaking)? If yes, you could explicitely introduce an interface/abstract class, if no, this seems like a conceptual error in the first place.

Comment: Even if you could, they would be nearly unusable.

Comment: @Smutje Yes I do process both kind of objects differently. But I want to provide a single interface to the user of my client APIs so that they can pass on any type among A or B.

That's exactly the reason I looked upon the generics as a last option. Precisely following types I intent to refer via A and B notations:
A -> com.google.gson.JsonElement
B -> org.w3c.dom.Document
They are not related at all by any interface/abstract class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make the constructor private:

```
private C(T param){
```

And then provide static factory methods to create instances of particular types:

```
public static <T extends A> C<T> create(T param) {
  return new C<>(param);
}

public static <T extends B> C<T> create(T param) {
  return new C<>(param);
}
```

This doesn't prevent you from using the *type* `C<SomeOtherType>`; you just can't create an instance of it.

Comment: Brilliant!!
Thank you :)

Comment: as there is only one parameter, you can also use public static C<T> create(T<T extends A>  param) {
  return new C<>(param);
}.

Comment: @Jayanth no, you can't write that.

Comment: because u declared C<T> as the return type?

Comment: @Jayanth you can only use extends in the declaration of the type variable; but also, `T` isn't in scope there, because it is a static method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that but you can set **boundaries** on what type you want to accept.

If you have

```
class A extends BaseType {}
class B extends BaseType {}
```

you can define the class `C` to be

```
class C<T extends BaseType> { ... }
```

Either a `class` or an `interface` as base type work.

Comment: I do not have the control over definitions of A and B

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *marker interface* for that:

```
interface AllowedInC {
    // intentionally empty because it will be used as a mere marker
}

class A implements AllowedInC {
    ...
}

class B implements AllowedInC {
    ...
}

class C<T extends AllowedInC> {
   ...
}
```

Only classes A or B (or another class implementing `AllowedInC`) will be useable in `C<T>`.