# Java generic parameter as exact subclass?

Tags: java, reflection, wildcard

Assuming we have a method like this:

```java
public void foo(Class<? extends ClassBar> x) {
    ...
}
```

By modifying the generic expression;

> < ? extends ClassBar >

Is it possible to ensure that *ClassBar.class* can't be passed in but anything extends ClassBar directly or indirectly be passed in **WITHOUT** throwing an exception on the runtime?

Comment: Hmm so therefore the only option is to see if it's Modifier.isAbstract(x.getModifiers()) or directly checking if it's ClassBar.class or not.

Comment: do you have many classes extending `ClassBar` ?

Comment: Yea, and want to hand them in except `ClassBar` to the `foo` method. Should I handle inside the method or is there a way to see that on compile time?

Comment: ok saw your comment too late

Comment: @luk2302 you still can pass `ClassBar.class` despite being `abstract`. He specifically wants to filter access to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only a bunch of classes extending `ClassBar` you can follow these two approaches.

---

**Solution 1:**

have all subclasses of `ClassBar` extend a custom `interface` (except for `ClassBar` itself), and change the method signature to:

```
public <T extends ClassBar & MyInterface> void foo(Class<T> x) {
    ...
}
```

**Solution 2:**

use something similar to [this @AndyTurner's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48824392/8524301) and provide instances only for specific types.

E.g:

```
class ClassBar {}

class ClassBarA extends ClassBar{}
class ClassBarB extends ClassBar{}
```

Your `class` containing `foo`:

```
class Foo<T extends ClassBar> {
    private Foo() {} // private constructor

    public static <T extends ClassBarA> Foo<T> instance(T c) {
        return new Foo<T>();
    }

    public static <T extends ClassBarB> Foo<T> instance(T c) {
        return new Foo<T>();
    }

    public void foo(Class<T> c) {

    }

}
```

Only subclass of `ClassBarA` would be accepted in this case

```
Foo<ClassBarA> foo1 = Foo.instance(this.classBarA);
foo1.foo(ClassBarA.class); // pass
foo1.foo(ClassBar.class);  // fail
```

Comment: `ClassBar` is going to be used as an `abstract` base for a handler class. So depending libraries can extend `ClassBar` to implement their own handlers. But I think there is no way to write an expression like `<? extends ClassBar & ? != ClassBar>`, I am going to count `<? extends ClassBar & SomeInterface>` as the best solution so far. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @iGoodie usually `handlers` are `interface`, which force you to have an implementation. I'd personally follow the standard pattern