# Complex type bounds

Tags: java

Assuming a given a class hierarchy

```
class Region{};
class Shape extends Region{};
class Triangle   extends Shape{};
class Circle     extends Shape{};
```

Is there a way to define a method accepting only `Shape` or `Triangle`, but not a `Circle` ?

I can preform run-time type check and throw exception, but compile-time type check would be much better. 
(For clarifications: by writing "given a class hierarchy" I mean it can not be changed).

Comment: From the object oriented point of view, a `Circle` **is a** `Shape`. So there is no way to declare a method that accepts a shape and then pretend that a circle is not a shape.

Comment: You can make Shape and Triangle, but not Circle implement an interface and pass this interface, instead of the Region class to your method.

Comment: @CostisAivalis if `Shape` implements an interface, `Circle` implements it as well. `Circle` **is a** `Shape`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, I am aware that `Circle` is a `Shape`. That is the basis for my question. If it were not, it would have been simple

Comment: @CostisAivalis the question assumes a given hierarchy

Comment: This smells a bit like an XY problem. Why do you need a method that will accept shapes that are not circles?

Comment: For example if you want  `findVertices(Shape shape)` and want to exclude shapes with no vertices.

Comment: @RealSkeptic You are right, My bad. I answered before reading the Q thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make such a check in compile time (given your current class hierarchy), since a `Circle` is a `Shape`, so any method that accepts a `Shape` argument would accept a `Circle` argument.

You'll have to change your class hierarchy or introduce some new interface.

Some options:

1. Introduce a sub-class of `Shape` that represents all the shapes that are not a `Circle` (let's call it `NotCircleShape`, though you should think of a positive description of what is common to all the shapes that are not a `Circle`), and let your method accept an argument of that sub-class.
2. Introduce an interface implemented by all the `Shape`s except of `Circle`, and let your method accept an argument of that interface.

Comment: I was afraid this  was the only options, which is not applicable for a given set of classes and hierarchy.  You wrote: "You'll **either** have to change your class hierarchy" which made me hope there is an **or**

Comment: @c0der yes, the language was a bit off due to some editing. The "or" was supposed to be introducing an interface.

Answer (score 1):

A change in the hierarchical design can help you achieve that, if you are of course **willing to re-design** the `class` system.

**Solution 1**: custom `interface`

Have `Triangle` and all other sub-classes of `Shape` except for `Circle` implement a custom `interface`. Given your use-case, let's call it

```
public interface NonEllipticalShape {}
```

Then change the method signature to

```
public <T extends Shape & NonEllipticalShape > void method(T t) {
    ...
}
```

This **does prevents** the type `Shape` to be passed as parameter though, but it does look as `Shape` shouldn't be an instantiable type anyway.

You'd therefore have, something like

```
class Circle extends Shape {}
class Triangle extends Shape implements NonEllipticalShape {}
class Rectangle extends Shape implements NonEllipticalShape {}
```

**Solution 2**: specific factory methods

Follow [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48824216/can-we-use-generic-to-allow-only-specific-types-instead-of-any-type-t/48824392#48824392) and provide instances of the utility class only to specific sub-types.

```
class MethodClass<T extends Region> {
    private MethodClass() {} // private constructor

    public static <T extends Triangle> MethodClass<T> instance(T c) {
        return new MethodClass<T>();
    }

    public static <T extends Rectangle> MethodClass<T> instance(T c) {
    return new MethodClass<T>();
    }

    public void method(T t) {

    }

}
```

Only classes allowed via the factory methods are allowed into `MethodClass` instances. Its methods will therefore be reserved only for the specific type `T` but this will require a factory method for each shape.

Here as well, the type `T extends Shape` shouldn't be accepted, or `Circle` will become a valid parameter.

Comment: Your first suggestion won't work in the current hierarchy because any interface implemented by `Shape` is inherited by `Circle`. And your second contains an unknown `AnotherShape` which you didn't explain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have factory or simply overloaded methods can help, but I don't see how it prevents using a `Circle`

Comment: definitely right. I realized after @RealSkeptic comment that I missed the point. I'm editing the answer although its mostly about class design refactoring then I'll apply it to my two examples. Might anyway be useful for some future reader who had your similar issue and are willing to redesign the hierarchy system

Comment: I agree. Without a good compile-time type-check solution, other solutions are relevant. I added a clarification to  my question, to clarify.

Comment: I can see the benefit of using generics if `instance(T t)` can accept a range of types. If it should accept a specific type you might as well simply have `instance(Triangle t)`

Comment: @c0der yes of course. Both generified or type-specific factory methods would work.